# parse facebook user timeline using php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on to fetch feed of user/page facebook timeline using php. So far I have to on this is:

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxx',
      'secret' => 'xxx',
    ));
    $username = isset($_GET['username'])?$_GET['username']:"agptj";
    $profile = $facebook->api('/'.$username.'/posts');
?>

<br/><br/><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$username?>/picture">

<?php
    foreach( $profile['data'] as $data ){
        if($data['message']){
            echo $data['message']."<br><hr><br>";
        }else{
            echo $data['story']."<br><hr><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

This is working fine with page: `$username = "mashable"`. But, when I try doing the same for profile, it shows the `activity log` instead of status updates. For example: `$username = "agptj"`

output:

`Prakash Timilsina updated his cover photo.`

How can I get the status updates not activity log of the profile using php?

**EDIT**:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'read_stream')
);
```

Logging in with scope `read_stream` and looking for `/statuses` as

`$profile = $facebook->api('/'.$username.'/statuses');`

Let me access my own profile and my friend's profile statuses but doesn't let me `read random person's public updates`. How can I do that?

Comment: have you tried it with read_stream permission? you may want to provide that access_token into api calls. you can quickly check it through their api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Comment: Hello @AtaurRahimChowdhury, could you please read the `Edit`

Comment: If you are still having problems, I tried to get public statuses of someone who is not my friend, i wasn't able to get it through explorer using statuses in the query. but with 'username/posts' i can see the recent posts he made. If you only want status you can filter it out by adding status_type with the query. here is the example query i tried with: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=hasin%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Dmessage%2Cid%2Ctype%2Cstatus_type%26limit%3D50%26since%3D1391280317

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook graph API doesn't let you access to `random profile's public updates`. The maximum what API lets, you're already upto it

**To verify my answer**

1. Open the graph explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/
2. Click on `Get Access Token` and get token for every `permissions` that facebook graph API allows. `User Data Permissions` `Friends Data Permissions` `Extended Permissions`
3. Now using `GET` method, let `/zuck/statuses` which is a public profile
4. You can see that returns nothing

   `{"data": []}`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read the feed of posts (including their status updates which are public) for a random user without his/her permission. You need a valid [User Access Token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens) from a user with a `read_stream` permission in order to do that.

With a valid Access Token, you can achieve this for a particular user or his/her friends by  either using the Graph API or by using an FQL query on the [stream](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) table. You can use a query like:

```
SELECT post_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id = {User_ID} LIMIT 50
```

Or, if you particularly concerned about the statuses of a user or his/her friends, you can use [status](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/status/) table like:

```
SELECT status_id, message FROM status WHERE uid = {User_ID} LIMIT 50
```

---

There is however a way to read the stream of user status updates and page status updates as they are posted to Facebook. This can be done by using the [Public Feed API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/). But this will only include status updates that have their privacy set to ‘public’ are included in the stream. Also, you cannot apply to use the API at this time as its access is limited.

Answer (score 0):

Use /statuses instead of /posts.

Answer (score 0):

Prakash, I'm sorry to tell you that you can not access the status of random user even if the privacy of this status is public, Unless you get a valid access token of that user or access token of one of his friends. I now this answer has the same mean of some previous answers but i wrote it to confirm these answers.

I have one question for you Mr,Prakash. Can you provide us, For what you want that? maybe we find anther method.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxx',
      'secret' => 'xxx',
    ));
    $username = isset($_GET['username'])?$_GET['username']:"agptj";
    $profile = $facebook->api('/'.$username.'/statuses');
?>

<br/><br/><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$username?>/picture">

<?php
    foreach( $profile['data'] as $data ){
        if($data['message']){
            echo $data['message']."<br><hr><br>";
        }else{
            echo $data['story']."<br><hr><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: http://eprakash.info/fb/index.php?username=agptj You can look at the site, that's not showing anything

Comment: I have `print_r($profile);` just after `$profile = ..;`

Comment: Are you sure you have proper access permissions for the API key?

Comment: `[25-Feb-2014 22:55:39] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught OAuthException: (#100) Requires user session
  thrown in /home/eprakash/public_html/fb/src/base_facebook.php on line 1340`

Comment: You need user_status permission for accessing status

Comment: I am not talking about to read my own status. I want to access my friend's or even public's status. which ever username is provided. What scope should be fit for that?